# Code that only runs when a Rails application is actually running, not during rake tasks, generators, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

We're trying to establish a block of gem-ready initialization code that runs exclusively in the context of a running Rails application, but it's proving mind-numbingly hard.

**We want it to run when:**

- An app is started locally from the command line via `rails server`
- An app is started on Heroku or other deployment environments
- During testing

**but NOT when:**

- A Rake task is being run
- A generator is being run
- Whatever is being run during the deploy process to Heroku

The last instance, especially, is tripping us up. Whenever we push to Heroku via `git push heroku master`, our app executes in some strange context where it's in production but no Heroku config variables are available to initializers.. can't find any info on it anywhere..

We've seen this [asked elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202862/running-rails-code-initializers-but-not-via-rake), but passing ENV variables isn't an option because it'll be in a gem.

Comment: I don’t really know enough about this to offer a full answer, but it sounds like you could use a lazy load hook: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/04/understanding-ruby-and-rails-lazy-load-hooks/. Also, the “strange context” when deploying to Heroku sounds like it could be the asset compilation step – “Environment variables are not available to your app at compile time”: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline.

Comment: @matt- thanks for two hugely helpful links. The asset pipeline article indeed sheds a lot of light on what we were dealing with there. As for lazy load hooks- sounds promising, I'm looking at them now and will report back..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can detect that you're in the Heroku asset pre-comp phase and avoid running some code, but you can get the Heroku environment variable to be available during pre-comp by using the 'user-env-compile' feature from Heroku Labs.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

```
 heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy- yea I saw that option. Though looks like it's an experimental feature and they're discouraging it...